# Can no longer scrape data from a web site

Tags: r, json, web-scraping

Up to about one month ago, I could use the code below to access the JSON file pointed to by this URL. Now I get the following error message:

```
library(RCurl)

url <- "https://petition.parliament.uk/archived/petitions/169973.json"
web <- getURL(url)

Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Is there a way to re-enable this kind of access? This is the relevant  sessionInfo(). Thanks.

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

other attached packages:
[1] RCurl_1.95-4.12 bitops_1.0-6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed the `RCurl` package seems a bit fussy about SSL certificates. While I'm sure there are ways to get around it, it seems the `httr` package is a bit better about it by default. Here's how you would use that package to get the data

```
library(httr)
url <- "https://petition.parliament.uk/archived/petitions/169973.json"
web <- content(GET(url))
```